# JavaScript Changing BG Color

Tags: javascript, css, html, colors, background

I made a div with background-color set to rgb(0,0,0); and I want to change it's color on click with javascript. I made a function to do that.

```
function change(){
var x = 1;
var y = x + 100;
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + y + "," + y + "," + y + ")"; }
```

It works fine but I can change the div's color just once. What I want to do is get div's color value and set it to x and run the function again. So the bg will go like black->grey->white on each click. Depending on the y variable.

I can get the div's value but it'll get it in "rgb(0,0,0);" format. I don't know what to do after getting this. How do I manipulate just integers in rgb(0,0,0); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store current `x` value in `data` attributes:

```
function change(box) {
    var x = +box.getAttribute('data-x'), // +box.dataset.x for modern browsers
        y = x + 100;
    box.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + y + "," + y + "," + y + ")";
    box.setAttribute('data-x', y);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box" onclick="change(this)"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wuz75/

Comment: Hello, tested your answer, nice work. Just would be good to add a cycle to it also. http://jsfiddle.net/Wuz75/1/ Greetings

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I was also going to add a cycle to it. So thank you both =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to analyse the color, since your colors will be static, just make an array of colors, and keep track of the index.

```
var colors = [
        "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "rgb(100,100,100)",
        "rgb(255,255,255)"
    ],
    c = 0;
```

Then in your function, use `c` to get the next color, and then increment, or reset to `0`.

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = colors[c];
    c = ++c % colors.length;
}
```

So whenever you run the function, it'll switch between colors in the Array.

Comment: Colors won't be static. Tho that's not necessary. Still I couldn't run your code. I'm new to JavaScript. Perhaps you can link a demo. Thanks.

Comment: @akinuri: http://jsfiddle.net/TBetW/ If the colors aren't static, what sort of calculation will be used?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Hmm well I haven't decided yet. I'm using JavaScript to make local apps with HTA. Just experimenting now.

Comment: @akinuri: You're welcome. Just for fun, I made a quick demo that generates random colors: http://jsfiddle.net/TBetW/1/

Comment: Haha. Thank you. This sure will come in handy =)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use :

```
function change(x) {
  var el = document.getElementById('color');
  var rgb = el.style.backgroundColor.replace(/rgb|\(|\)|\s/g, '').split(',');

  if ( rgb == "" ) { rgb = [0,0,0] };

  for (var a = 0; a < rgb.length; a++ ) {
    rgb[a] = parseInt(rgb[a]) + x;
  }

  el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')';
}
```

Here is a demo : http://jsbin.com/ozepaz/1/edit